# Is the knock an early sign of Dual Mass Flywheel problem. Main dealer says acceptable noise?

Tags: ford, clutch, mondeo

Ford Mondeo 2012 1.6 TDCi DPF SS 115. At 15,500 mls I am experiencing a knocking sound when raising the clutch pedal but only when the engine is running. The sound outside the car is really loud. It is still in warranty. Initially Evans Halshaw said they could hear it but needed the car for 2 days. During that time all they did was a couple of road tests to advise me that the noise was normal and acceptable and a characteristic of the vehicle. They also said there was a small amount of backlash in gear. They suggested they have spoken to Ford who also said it was normal.  So why am I just experiencing the noise? I am concerned as there is so much talk of manufacturers denying responsibility and avoiding warranty work, and a lot of concerns about the Dual Mass Clutch. A problem now will only get worse, what can I do now except put it back in again, to expect the same answer?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to say anything about the dealership you mention that a quick Google of review sites for them wouldn't reveal anyway.

Yes, knocking is an early sign of the dual-mass clutch-flywheel assembly beginning to wear out.  How long you will have between audible knocking and replacement is hard to predict.

If you are unsure or unhappy about your main dealers assertion that the noise is acceptable, take the vehicle elsewhere for an independent assessment.  Presumably the dealership that's assessed it provided you with the car in the first place so would have to shoulder the cost of replacement.  Try another Ford dealership or service centre and see what their opinion of the noise is.